Does GitHub support anything like GitLab's !reference (or YAML Anchors)?
Does GitHub support anything that allows you to create snippets like GitLab's !reference? I'm looking to reduce code duplication in a workflow?

No. The advantage to !reference compared to "YAML Anchors" is that it works over foreign yaml include,

You can’t use YAML anchors across multiple files when using the include keyword. Anchors are only valid in the file they were defined in. To reuse configuration from different YAML files, use !reference tags or the extends keyword.

However, GitHub doesn't have YAML Anchors either. But there is a feature request for that.
